# Using the same cmake target with 2 different configs

Tags: cmake

I'm using a third party library, Scheme S7, in my codebase which is made up of one header and one source. I'm using this external code in 2 of my libraries. In one library, I need to include the source of the S7 library and set some #defines, but in the 2nd I only need to include the header, and have a different set of defines.

Is there a way to create a target such that it works for both scenarios, or do I need to create 2 different targets for this. The first target, which includes the source file is defined like this:

```
add_library(third_party_scheme INTERFACE)
add_library(third_party::scheme ALIAS third_party_scheme)

target_sources(third_party_scheme
    INTERFACE
        "scheme/s7.c"
)

target_compile_definitions(third_party_scheme
    INTERFACE 
        S7_EXPORT_LIB
        S7_OUTPUT_FUNCTION_FULL_STRING
)
```

Comment: For expose different properties (sources, macro definitions) you need to create different targets. Not sure why do you expect a single target be able to fulfill both requirements.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I had no expectation. I was wondering if it was possible. For example, there are generator-expressions that can change aspects of a target, depending on the ide config, so it wasn't inconceivable for there to be a mechanism to allow different operations on different targets using the same config.

Comment: It's odd that this is an INTERFACE target. I do not understand why is it INTERFACE, - it has a source file, to be compiled, I would do it just a library.

Comment: "For example, there are generator-expressions that can change aspects of a target, depending on the ide config" - Yes, INTERFACE properties of the library could use [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html), so they will be evaluated depending on the consumer's properties... But what **consumer properties** you want to depend on? What kind of "ide config" you are talking about? E.g. you could depend on compile language (`$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE>`), but one cannot depend on the name of the consumer target.

Answer (score 0):

So just create two targets.

```
add_library(third_party_scheme "scheme/s7.c")
target_compile_definitions(third_party_scheme PUBLIC 
    S7_EXPORT_LIB
    S7_OUTPUT_FUNCTION_FULL_STRING
)

add_library(third_party_scheme2 "scheme/s7.c")
# no target_compile_definitions, or different ones.
```

> do I need to create 2 different targets for this

Yes. You could do a function, like:

```
function(add_third_party_scheme_target name)
       add_library(${name} scheme/s7.c)
       target_compile_definitions(third_party_scheme PUBLIC 
             ${ARGV}
       )
endfunction()

add_third_party_scheme_target(third_party_scheme
    S7_EXPORT_LIB
    S7_OUTPUT_FUNCTION_FULL_STRING
)
add_third_party_scheme_target(third_party_scheme2
)
```